# Bootstrap flex layout - div in main section not expanding to fill its parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I've a header/main/footer layout in Bootstrap 5.2, where I'd like the main section to expand to fill the page between the header and footer.

The following code works:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <header>
    H
  </header>
  <main class="flex-grow-1" style="background: blue;">
    <div style="background: yellow; height: 100%;">
      M
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    F
  </footer>
</body>
```

But I'd like the div inside the main to fill its parent.   As things stand, it does so horizontally, but not vertically.

What am I missing?

Comment: replace min-vh-100 by vh-100

Answer (score 1):

Adding:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

to my css has fixed it.

Comment: you could also turn main into a flex container ... https://jsfiddle.net/s7na6dp2/ Or a grid of a single cell https://jsfiddle.net/Ld63gmrf/ ;)